# The side panel shows strange characters in TeXstudio 2.12.16

Tags: texstudio

When I using TeXstudio 2.12.16  on Debian Buster, the side panel can not show the proper characters, but some strange ones. Blow is the screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, the left lower part of the picture shows some strange characters. I can not fix this problem. I set all the fonts to be WenQuanYi Micro Hei, with encoding UTF-8. The locale of my Linux is:
[08/28/2019,08:50:42@~]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

How can I solve this strange problem?

PS: I have changed LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8 back into LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8. But the same problem is still there. Then, I test in another computer (Call it B), whose OS is the same as the one which has the problem, even the edition of texstudio is the same. It is very strange that, in B, texstudio works very well.

Comment: BTW, when I compile the source file in TeXMaker, all things go smoothly, particularly the symbols show correctly on the left panel. Hence I guess it is a bug of TeXstudio.

Comment: Texstudio is in version 4.3.0 now

Answer (score 1):

From the github, it caused by the package qt5dxcb-plugin. Here's [a link](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/709)!

Therefore the simplest way is to remove this package